# After modifying mac address of Windows 10, Windows 10 mobile hotspot stopped working

Tags: windows-10, android, iphone, mac-address, hotspot

I searched all the internet for the solution. No luck!

After changing my mac address using the software Technitium MAC Changer v6.0.7, i can no longer connect to the hotspot. I've tried to connect to hotspot with an IPhone, and Android.

I don’t get any errors on my Windows when I turn on the hotspot, but I can’t connect to it.

Windows 10 is on LAN. The internet works fine

How can resolve this issue or how can I change MAC not encountering this issue?

UPDATE:
Problem appears when I change particularly this MAC address:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : wmi.amu.edu.pl
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 80-77-21-75-34-C3
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

References
[Wifi not working after I changed MAC address](https://superuser.com/questions/1713117/wifi-not-working-after-i-changed-mac-address)
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiNocPlzbz4AhUBAxAIHTWZDHUQFnoECCEQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fanswers.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fwindows%2Fforum%2Fall%2Fmobile-hotspot-issue-after-changing-mac-address%2Fe647da46-eefd-4fd1-8cd4-1186ea37dc88&usg=AOvVaw3_6w-ygJ-5OZh9cPI2phmI
https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/mobile-hotspot-doesnt-work-after-changing-mac-address.188241/

Comment: The MAC address on my iPhone 13 changes frequently (I do not change it manually) and I have to work carefully to enter the iPhone MAC address into my Router DHCP reservation table. I expect this is why you cannot change it yourself.

Comment: @John but I changed the MAC address of my Windows 10, not the MAC address of my IPhone

Comment: I will reflect on that. I am not sure why changing Windows would not work.

Comment: Try to reboot the router and Windows (in that order). Does Windows have internet? Does the hotspot work? Question: How is the computer connected to the router?

Comment: @harrymc thank you for taking the look. Win10 has the access to internet; it works fine. However, I am connected with LAN and I don't have the access to the router or whatever it is connected to.

Comment: Maybe try a USB Wireless NIC and see if you can change the MAC address with that.  Also try use Network Adapter Properties to change MAC instead of Technitium software.

Comment: What do you men by "I don't have the access to the router"?

Comment: @harrymc it is in the server room that I don't have the access to. i live in the dorms

Comment: Do you have access to the router's settings page?

Comment: @harrymc no. if it helps, here is the [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi8xJ-_6r74AhVw_SoKHeSbAcsQ-TAoAHoECEMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Feduroam.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw3JOXhTGI_hOj_jDQX9EPYi) to my IPS

Comment: @John I updated the question

Comment: @harrymc I updated the question

Comment: Try the advice in [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/mobile-hotspot-issue-after-changing-mac-address/e647da46-eefd-4fd1-8cd4-1186ea37dc88) (even if it didn't help the poster).